# could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet

Tags: rest, spring-boot, sql-delete

I want to insert some data, and before inserting I want to delete previous data regarding that.But getting "could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet" this error.

My controller class

```
@PostMapping(path="signin",produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody public LoginView loginProcess( @RequestBody User user){

try {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    Date newdate = new Date(date.getTime()+9*3600*1000);

this.loginRepository.delete(user.getUsername());
this.loginRepository.insert(user.getUsername(),user.getDetails(),dateFormat.format(date),dateFormat.format(newdate));

catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Repository class

```
public interface LoginRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>{


@Query(value="INSERT INTO DBA.TOKEN_DETAILS (username,TOKEN,ACTIVE,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO) VALUES(:username,:token,1,:validFrom,:validTo)",nativeQuery=true)
public void insertToken(@Param("username")String username, @Param("token")String token, @Param("validFrom")String validFrom, @Param("validTo")String validTo);

@Transactional
@Modifying 
@Query(value="DELETE FROM DBA.TOKEN_DETAILS WHERE username=?1",nativeQuery=true)
public void deleteToken(String username);

}
```

The error log I am getting is -

```
2019-06-12 15:52:10.654  WARN 11120 --- [nio-8087-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: JZ0R2
2019-06-12 15:52:10.654 ERROR 11120 --- [nio-8087-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : JZ0R2: No result set for this query.
could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Comment: Data is getting inserted, but in code throwing error.

Answer (score 2):

It has been resolved by adding a @Modifying annotation in repository class

```
@Modifying
    @Query(value="INSERT INTO DBA.TOKEN_DETAILS (username,TOKEN,ACTIVE,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO) VALUES(:username,:token,1,:validFrom,:validTo)",nativeQuery=true)
    public void insertToken(@Param("username")String username, @Param("token")String token, @Param("validFrom")String validFrom, @Param("validTo")String validTo);
```